# Configure Android for ONLY IPv6 on T-Mobile

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, mobile-network, ipv6

I figured out how to configure a dual-stack IPv4/IPv6 "Access Point" for T-Mobile connectivity on my Samsung Galaxy Nexus, with stock Android 4.2.2. For some reason, when I visit http://myglobalip.com, I'm still getting an IPv4 address returned in addition to the IPv6 address.

**Question:** How do I configure the "Access Point" so that it **only** gets an IPv6 address, and **not** an IPv4 address?

My current IPv6 "Access Point" configuration looks like:

```
APN: epc.tmobile.com
Proxy: Not set
Port: Not set
Username: Not set
Password: Not set
Server: Not set
MMSC: Not set
MMS proxy: Not set
MMS port: Not set
MCC: 310
MNC: 260
Authentication type: Not set
APN type: Not set
APN protocol: IPv6
APN roaming protocol: IPv4
Bearer: Unspecified
```

Comment: I've also tried configuring the APN roaming protocol to `IPv6` which hasn't helped at all. I'm still getting an IPv4 address as well.

Answer (score 2):

**Update [2013-04-30]:** I believe the reason I am still able to access IPv4 websites, is because of DNS64+NAT64. The public IP address I'm getting from http://myglobalip.com is the public IPv4 interface of the NAT64 gateway.

I think the answer to this question is: T-Mobile uses some sort of transitional technology called **464XLAT** to provide IPv4 connectivity over an IPv6-only GSM wireless network. There is more information about 464XLAT at this URL: https://sites.google.com/site/tmoipv6/464xlat.

Ultimately, it doesn't seem possible to disable IPv4 functionality altogether. Obviously, doing so would break a lot of applications from functioning properly, but I really wanted to do so entirely for testing purposes, to see what would and would not work.

The part that confuses me is that the 464XLAT RFC requires a "CLAT" daemon, which I don't believe exists on my stock Galaxy Nexus 4.2.2 Jelly Bean ROM. With this in mind, I'm not entirely sure what sort of configuration I'm running.

Here is the [464XLAT RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6877).

If I use an app called [Network Info II](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=aws.apps.networkInfoIi&hl=en) to view network interface information for **rmnet0** on my Galaxy Nexus, I can see that I have ONLY an IPv6 address configured. In fact, the app even has an IPv6 "tab" specifically designed for viewing IPv6 information. I cannot see any IPv4 information when I have selected IPv6 as the APN.

More T-Mobile IPv6 information can be found:

- [T-Mobile IPv6 is Here and Now](https://sites.google.com/site/tmoipv6/lg-mytouch)
- [Top Free Apps on T-Mobile IPv6-only Network](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnVbRg3DotzFdGVwZWlWeG5wXzVMcG5qczZEZloxWGc#gid=0)